# Xamarin CollectionView scroll to bottom at initialization

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I make sure that a `CollectionView` displays the last item i.e. the bottom one, from the start without the user having to scroll all the way down.

I use this in a chat UI that I created and want to make sure that the latest messages are in user's view right from the beginning and the user can always scroll up to see older messages.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/scrolling

Answer (score 3):

Set a command in your VM that you can execute when the data is loaded or changed and listen for it in the view and do the scrolling there.

In your VM:

```
public Command CollectionUpdatedCommand { get; set; }
```

And then, once the collection changes, whenever you need to fire it:

```
CollectionUpdatedCommand?.Execute(null);
```

In your view, set the scroll code to execute when the command is executed:

```
viewModel.CollectionUpdatedCommand = new Command(() =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        MessageList.ScrollTo(viewModel.Messages.Last(), null, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
    });
});
```

Comment: With this approach, aren't we violating the main MVVM idea of not tightly coupling the UI with the view model though?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't see it as any different than binding to a command in the XAML file. Ultimately it's your call though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this along the OnAppearing() :

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
  MessageList.ScrollTo(viewModel.Messages.Last(), null, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
});`
```

Where **MessageList** - it's your **CollectionView**
and
**viewModel.Messages** - it's your Messages collection for this CollectionView e.g. ObservableCollection

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: This makes sense but the issue is that this is happening before I populate the `CollectionView`. I have an `Init()` method in my view model and I call this method from `OnAppearing()` method. So, when I try to set the scroll location in `OnAppearing()` method, I get an error because the API call is not yet finalized to populate the `CollectionView` in my `Init()` mehtod.